# Does this registration process seem simple enough?

Tags: ajax, web, process, paypal, registration

Building a website that has English & Japanese speaking users, with the Japanese users being actual paying customers (they're businesses looking to promote their presence). Their registration process is a tad different than the English users.

Here's what I had in mind, tell me if there are any glaring mistakes I should avoid:

User -> Homepage -> Info Page -> Signup Page -> Payment Page -> Welcome

Everything up to the signup page is typical. The signup page has 2 "steps" (setup similar to [basecamphq.com](http://basecamphq.com)). They enter their desired user info and then their company info. In the company info section there is a map to click to pinpoint their position in longitude/latitude (so they don't have to enter the values themselves).

Then they hit "next step", where they're greeted, told to check their email for a verification code, and shown a textbox. In the textbox they enter the verification code and click verify.

There's a small ajax based check done, if successful their account is activated and they're shown the paypal payment button (no page refreshes, just a small fadeout/fade in animation).

Then it's the typical pay at paypal get returned to a thank you page routine.

Does this sound like a good registration process? Can you see any pitfalls with the way it flows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems fairly standard.  The only thing I would add is a link in the email for in case something happens in step 2 (browser crashes, email client is on another computer, whatever) and you need to get back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is working great - keeping in mind the e-mails that are sent to assist users in case they left in the middle of the process.